# Define class property types in typescript?

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I'm using ES6 classes in typescript with the following:

```
class Camera {
    constructor(ip) {
        this.ip = ip;
    }
}
```

I get back this error, *though it still seems to compile*:

> Property 'ip' does not exist on type 'Camera'.

If I define the type:

```
this.ip: string = ip;
```

I get back:

> ';' expected.

How should I format the class to get rid of both errors?

Comment: By declaring the member variable in the class. Now it is not declared anywhere. You can't define a type on assignment. But you can define the variable in the constructor argument list.

Comment: *How should I format the class to get rid of both errors?* By reading the documentation, or looking through any of hundreds of tutorials, intros, and blog posts. BTW, it is misleading to say "using ES6 classes in TypeScript". Although the two are quite close, TypeScript classes are **not** ES6 classes.

Comment: @torazaburo thanks for the tip, why not post your answer if you really consider it a solution.

Comment: @PhilipKirkbride Because I don't post "solutions" which are nothing more than regurgitating rudimentary knowledge which is widely available from documentation and many other sources, and I don't support the use of SO as a human-powered on-demand chatroom-like alternative for reading the manual.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Either declare the property on the class first:

```
class Camera {
    ip: string;
    constructor(ip: string) {
        this.ip = ip;
    }
}
```

Or declare it on the constructor parameter (the preferred approach), just add an access modifier (`public` or `private`) to the parameter to indicate it is a property:

```
class Camera {
    constructor(public ip: string) {
        // note no explicit assignment
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have tried to access the property "ip" without definng it in the class itself. 
The constructer(ip){} is called when you call the Camera class and it search for the ip property.Since you have not defined it in the class gives an error

use this way. best wishes.

```
class Camera {
 private ip: string;  // declare your variable first with the type

  constructor(ip) {
    this.ip = ip;
  }
}
```